# Given two lists, how to create a unique combinations and the elements in each combination are different? Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, sorting, combinations

Inputs:

```
list1 = ['Town1','Town2','Town3','Town4','Town5']

list2 = ['Town1','Town2','Town3','Town4','Town5']
```

Outputs:

```
[('Town1', 'Town2'), ('Town3', 'Town4'), ('Town4', 'Town4'), ('Town4', 'Town5'), ('Town1', 'Town4'), ('Town3', 'Town5'), ('Town1', 'Town3'), ('Town2', 'Town4'), ('Town1', 'Town5'), ('Town2', 'Town3'), ('Town2', 'Town5')]
```

I tried :

```
comb = list(product(list1,list2))
comb1 = [sorted(item) for item in comb]
comb2 = list(set(map(tuple,comb1)))
```

But `('Town1', 'Town1')` is involved in the result.

Comment: Is the result the expected output? If so why do you have `Town4, Town4`?

Comment: Are the two list always identical? If not, better provide a more meaningful example.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the pairs with repeated elements with a [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html):

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ['Town1','Town2','Town3','Town4','Town5']

list2 = ['Town1','Town2','Town3','Town4','Town5']

comb = [pair for pair in product(list1,list2) if pair[0] != pair[1]]
print(comb)
```

The output is:

```
[('Town1', 'Town2'), ('Town1', 'Town3'), ('Town1', 'Town4'), ('Town1', 'Town5'), ('Town2', 'Town1'), ('Town2', 'Town3'), ('Town2', 'Town4'), ('Town2', 'Town5'), ('Town3', 'Town1'), ('Town3', 'Town2'), ('Town3', 'Town4'), ('Town3', 'Town5'), ('Town4', 'Town1'), ('Town4', 'Town2'), ('Town4', 'Town3'), ('Town4', 'Town5'), ('Town5', 'Town1'), ('Town5', 'Town2'), ('Town5', 'Town3'), ('Town5', 'Town4')]
```

Comment: Or equivalently `[(a, b) for a in list1 for b in list2 if a != b]`

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['Town1','Town2','Town3','Town4','Town5']
list2 = ['Town1','Town2','Town3','Town4','Town5']

result = []

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i != j:
            result.append((i, j))

print(result)
```